Snowflake Dashboard Context Selector Unselects Warehouse Moments After Run/Fails: 000606 (57P03): No active warehouse selected in the current session
I recently created a new dashboard (1st snowflake dash) to monitor resource consumption. Throughout development I had friction getting queries to run consistently due to:
"000606 (57P03): No active warehouse selected in the current session. Select an active warehouse with the 'use warehouse' command."
The problem is whenever I select a role/warehouse and run my dashboard, the "context selector" for warehouse defaults back to "No warehouse selected" approximately 3-4s after clicking "run", and all running queries/tiles fail.
All of the queries will run successfully when ran in a standalone SQL worksheet with the same role/warehouse.
It is worth calling out that many of my queries in the dash use the :daterange filter. I thought maybe this was the root of my problems, but the error reproduces across all queries regardless of :daterange usage.
I tried multiple workarounds, all of which "solve" the issue transiently until you change a filter or come back for fresh data the next day. I tried:

Setting up queries in a folder first, selecting appropriate roles/warehouse/environment + running to completion/success, formatting visuals -> then moving into dashboard.
Tried running USE WAREHOUSE in the Dashboard Query Worksheet UI -> fails with error (paraphrasing) "must select warehouse using dashboard, not in query UI". Although it throws an error, after you run the command, you can successfully query data in the UI and produce an output in the dashboard, but this only lasts until you try to query again using the dashboard run button.

Again, all of these workarounds produce data/charges 1 time, and after that the dashboard is useless unless you repeat steps 1 or 2 for each tile (not feasible).
The issue seems to come from the context selector, but I have never had issues with it outside of dashboards. To recap: I select a role (the role has appropriate permissions... I use it all over the DW with no issues), I select the warehouse I always use, I run the dashboard, it loads for 3-4s and then defaults to "No Warehouse Selected", then queries fail with the aforementioned error.

It's hard to tell what the issue might be from the information that you've provided, but it sounds like a permissions issue of some kind.  Have you reached out to Snowflake Support?

@MikeWalton - I have not contacted snowflake support... will try that. I suspected permission issues but having trouble conceptualizing why they would only materialize in the dashboard UI and not in any other Snowsight tool. One other thing I tried was creating a new dash ensuring it was created with the same (highest privilege) role I need to run with. I thought may I had initially created the dash with a lower-level role active. Unfortunately I was able to reproduce the same error so no progress.
